# How to convert a Control Flow Graph back into its source code? e.g., C/C++

Tags: llvm

I have already generated the corresponding CFG of my source code. Then, I want to modify the CFG (merge some nodes). In then end, I need to convert the modified CFG back into a corresponding source code. How could I do that? I am using LLVM at this point.

Comment: To *a* source code representation or *the*? If you want, say, a C representation, there's a backend that'll generates C. But it doesn't try to match your input (say, if you prefer to use `for` for most loops, that backend might express loops using `while` instead), and it generates C even if the source code was in Julia, Ada or Brainfuck.

Comment: It is totally ok that the outputted source code has its own style, as long as it is consistent with the modified CFG. Where can I find that "backend"?

Comment: The top google hit is https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe, but you can look at the rest of the results, too, maybe something else suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deceptively difficult problem. Usually the CFG is simplified
so that the original source code cannot be reconstructed. For example,
while and for-loops are replaced with tests and conditional jump
instructions. I'm sure that is the case for LLVM:s intermediate form
so you are out of luck there.

However, if the CFG has not been simplified it is possible to recreate
the program's abstract syntax tree (AST). To do that you need to have
the basic blocks of the CFG in program order. This is not difficult
since that is the natural order you get when creating the CFG. You
also need to precompute every basic block's immediate dominator. You
can find an algorithm for computing that in the article [A Simple,
Fast Dominance
Algorithm](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ekeith/EMBED/dom.pdf). Then the
algorithm proceeds as follows:

1. For every block except for the first one:

   1. Check whether this block is the direct child of its immediate
      dominator. I.e, whether this block is the first block in a
      while, for, or if-else clause.

      1. If yes, add the block to its immediate dominator's children.
      2. If no, mark this block as its immediate dominator's follower.
2. Use the collected data to build an AST as follows:
3. Traverse the follower data from the first block in the CFG until
   the last block which has no follower.

   1. For every block that is a for, if, or while, recurse from step 3
      but start with the first and second child (in case of else) of
      the block.

Here is some Python code that implements the algorithm:

```
from ast import *

class BasicBlock:
    def __init__(self, insns):
        self.insns = insns

    def type(self):
        return type(self.insns[-1]) if self.insns else None

def build_tree(bb, foll, children):
    nodes = []
    while bb:
        if not bb.insns:
            break
        last_insn = bb.insns[-1]
        childs = children[bb]
        tp = bb.type()
        if tp in (For, If, While):
            last_insn.body = \
                build_tree(childs[0], foll, children)
            if len(childs) == 2:
                last_insn.orelse = \
                    build_tree(childs[1], foll, children)
        nodes.extend(bb.insns)
        bb = foll.get(bb)
    return nodes

def is_dom_child(bb, dom_bb, succ):
    childs = succ[dom_bb]
    if bb in childs:
        tp = dom_bb.type()
        if tp in (If, For, While) and childs[0] == bb:
            return True
        if (tp == If and bb == childs[1] and
            not reachable(succ, childs[0], childs[1], {dom_bb})):
            return True
    return False

def bbs_to_ast(bbs, succ, idoms):
    foll = {}
    children = defaultdict(list)
    for bb in bbs[1:]:
        dom_bb = idoms[bb]
        if is_dom_child(bb, dom_bb, succ):
            children[dom_bb].append(bb)
        else:
            foll[dom_bb] = bb
    nodes = build_tree(bbs[0], foll, children)
    return Module(nodes, [])

def print_bbs(bbs, succ, idoms):
    mod = bbs_to_ast(bbs,  succ, idoms)
    return unparse(mod)
```